# Глобальные переменные в Python: сохранить локальную переменную от вызова к вызову функции

Tags: python

У меня есть функция, которой необходимо сохранять значение от вызова к вызову, при этом это значение используется только в этой функции. Как правильно использовать глобальные переменные в Python? Я пробовал написать нечто подобное:

```
someGlobalVar = 0

def incrimentGlobalVar()
    someGlobalVar = someGlobalVar + 1
```

Но данный код не работает. Может есть другие способы решения данной задачи?

Comment: можно просто параметр использовать: `def increment(counter=[0]): counter[0] += 1; return counter[0]` или [closure использовать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/141426/4279). В обоих случаях глобальные переменные не используются.

Comment: Интересное решение!

Comment: безопасная версия для многопоточных приложений (на CPython): `increment = functools.partial(next, itertools.count())`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Есть несколько способов реализовать подобное поведение.

### Глобальные переменные

Первое, что может прийти в голову, это использовать глобальные переменные.
Важно учитывать то, что глобальные переменные доступы на чтение

```
def func1():
    print(x)

x = 10
func1()   # 10
```

но простое использование на запись не разрешается:

```
def func2():
    y = 20    # создаёт локальную переменную, а не изменяет глобальную

y = 10
func2()
print(y)      # 10
```

Более того, при попытке обратиться к переменной сначала на чтение, потом на запись, мы получим ошибку:

```
def func3():
    print(z)
    z = 20

z = 10
func3()   # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

Это происходит из-за того, что использование присваивания переменной `z` обозначает её, как локальную (как в случае 2). Попытка вывести значение локальной переменной, у которой ещё не задано значение, как раз и порождает возникновение этой ошибки.

Аналогичный пример как раз приведён в вашем вопросе. Там тоже переменная `someGlobalVar` определяется, как локальная, потому что выполняется присваивание. Так как в этом присваивании используется сначала чтение значения ещё не инициализированной переменной `someGlobalVar`, мы получаем ту же ошибку.

---

Для того, чтобы этот пример работал, необходимо предварительно пометить переменную, как `global`:

```
def func4():
    global w
    print(w)
    w = 20


w = 10
func4()    # 10
print(w)   # 20
```

Аналогично будет работать и в вашем случае.

---

### Использование поля функции

Второй способ, который может прийти в голову, это использование объекта функции для хранения состояния функции.

```
def func5():
    if not hasattr(func5, '_state'):  # инициализация значения
        func5._state = 0
    print(func5._state)
    func5._state = func5._state + 1


# до первого вызова функции значение не установлено
# print(func5._state)  # AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_state'
func5()                # 0
print(func5._state)    # 1
```

В этом способе удобно то, что значение ассоциировано с самой функцией.

Стоит быть осторожным, давая имена подобным полям функции, так как в Python 2 у функции есть стандартные поля с названиями, не начинающимися с двух подчёркиваний, например, `func_closure`, `func_code` и т.п. Все они начинаются с `func_`, поэтому главное не использовать этот префикс и не начинать название поля с `__`, в остальных случаях шанс коллизии имён практически равен нулю.

---

### Использование класса с поведением функции

Третий способ заключается в создании класса с поведением функции. Это наиболее удобный и безопасный, по моему мнению, способ реализации подобного поведения. Просто создайте класс и перегрузите его метод `__call__`:

```
class FuncCreator:
    def __init__(self, start_state):
        self.state = start_state

    def __call__(self):
        print(self.state)
        self.state += 1


func6 = FuncCreator(0)
print(func6.state)  # 0
func6()             # 0
print(func6.state)  # 1
```

Это увеличивает объём кода, но добавляет удобств от использования функциональности класса.

---

### Использование изменяемого объекта, как значение по умолчанию для параметра

Четвёртый способ заключается в том, чтобы создать функцию, у которой будет необязательный параметр, использующий изменяемое значение в качестве состояния:

```
def func7(state=[]):
    if not state:
        state.append(0)
    print(state[0])
    state[0] += 1


func7()  # 0
func7()  # 1
```

В качестве объекта состояния можно использовать любой изменяемый объект. Это использует то, что все значения по умолчанию присваиваются один раз.

---

### Использование декоратора, выполняющего необходимые вычисления

Если вернуться к исходному примеру, то для подсчёта числа вызовов функции будет также может быть удобно использовать декораторы. Это позволит в том числе и переиспользовать код.

Для Python 3 код может выглядеть, например, так:

```
from functools import wraps


def call_count(func):
    count = 0
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(count)
    return wrapper
```

В Python 2 нет `nonlocal`, но можно использовать изменяемые переменные:

```
from functools import wraps


def call_count(func):
    count = [0]
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        count[0] += 1
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(count[0])
    return wrapper
```

Использоваться это будет следующим образом:

```
@call_count
def f():
    pass

f()  # 1
f()  # 2
```

При желании вы можете скомбинировать этот способ с каким-нибудь из описанных ранее.

---

Из всех выше упомянутых способов я бы рекомендовал использовать классы (так как функция с изменяющимся состоянием уже больше похожа на класс, чем на функцию) или поле функции, в случае необходимости быстрого добавления функциональности в код.

Comment: `func5._state` вариант лучше не использовать. `FuncCreator()` возможно подходит в сложных случаях, но чаще всего `func7()` с изменяемым параметром (лучше с `_` имя начать) или разновидность этого варианта с nonlocal можно использовать ([closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/141426/4279)) -- без выделения вычислений в отдельную функцию как в `call_count()` варианте.

Answer (score 11):

Если глобальная переменная изменяется в функции, ее необходимо объявить.

```
someGlobalVar = 0

def incrimentGlobalVar()
    global someGlobalVar
    someGlobalVar = someGlobalVar + 1
```

Если глобальная переменная используется только для чтения, то ее не нужно объявлять.

```
def print_someGlobalVar():
    print someGlobalVar
```

Для сохранения контекста лучше не использовать глобальные переменные. Что именно использовать, надо смотреть по обстоятельствам.

Answer (score 6):

Глобальные переменные - зло, лучше сделать так:

```
def incrimentGlobalVar():
    incrimentGlobalVar._someVar = incrimentGlobalVar._someVar + 1 if hasattr(incrimentGlobalVar, "_someVar") else 0
```

Answer (score 4):

В Питоне 3 можно использовать nonlocal с  [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141426/4279):

```
def make_counter():
    i = 0
    def counter(): # counter() is a closure
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        return i
    return counter

increment = make_counter()
print(increment(), increment())  # -> 1 2
```

На более ранних версиях можно было эмулировать nonlocal, используя изменяемый параметр:

```
def increment(counter=[0]):
    counter[0] += 1
    return counter[0]

print increment(), increment()  # -> 1 2
```

Можно явный объект использовать:

```
import functools 
import itertools

increment = functools.partial(next, itertools.count(1))
```

Здесь используется [существующая функция  `itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), можно и свою определить:

```
def count(i=0):
    while True:
        yield i 
        i += 1
```