# Python - Flask, изменение переменной через POST запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, flask

Не нашел в документации и в гугле, как изменить переменную через POST запрос. 
У меня есть глобальная переменная `video_fm = '.h264'`

Далее начальный код начинается вот так:

```
 @app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
 def post_test():
    global video_fmt
```

Далее не знаю, как при обработке пост запроса сменить значение у глобальной переменной

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Глобальные переменные в Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/358/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: @m9_psy нет не дубликат. Вы явно не поняли вопроса совсем.

Comment: Мой вопрос аналогичный.
Мне нужно при помощи запроса изменить то, что находится в context_processor, причём сделать это надо ни с какого-то определённого урла (в вашем случае /test), а из base.html , к которому никаких роутов, естественно, не ведёт. 
Так же, не нашёл ответа не вопрос.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik задайте новый вопрос. Для себя я нашел ответ и постораюсь помочь вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, request
...

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def post_test():
    global video_fmt

    # Смотрим что пришло в параметрах запроса
    print(request.args)
    
    # Вытаскиваем значение параметра text
    video_fmt = request.args.get('text')
```

---

**PS**

Вместо глобальной переменной, предлагаю [использовать глобальный словарь](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/game__guess_the_number__webserver__flask.py#L19).

Тогда код станет таким:

```
from flask import Flask, request
...

DATA = {
    'video_fmt': '.h264',
}


@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def post_test():
    # Смотрим что пришло в параметрах запроса
    print(request.args)

    # Вытаскиваем значение параметра text
    DATA['video_fmt'] = request.args.get('text')
```

---

**PPS**

Есть и другие данные, которые можно из запроса вытащить, например:

- `request.data` – тело запроса
- `request.form` – параметры из формы (`<form>`)
- `request.files` – переданные на сервер файлы

Comment: Делал пару недель назад интереса ради сервер для простенькой игры в "угадай число", там тоже post и глобальные переменные используются: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/game__guess_the_number__webserver__flask.py

Comment: хоть уже лично для меня и не востребован ответ, ибо ответ давно нашел, все равно спасибо :)

Comment: Я не заметил что вопросу уже 2 года :D

Comment: я тогда еще учился на программиста xD