# не понимаю поведение глобальных переменных в python

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

есть сервис(на flask), он принимает запросы клиентов, есть цепочка функций которая работает с пользовательскими переменными. мне надо что бы в каждой они были доступны без передачи в параметрах.

примерная структура приложения:

```
1. ls = "!"    

2. @app.route('/<tx>')
3.    def get_phrase(tx):#точка входа   
4.        ls = request.cookies.get('ls')

5.        if True:
6.            return get_info()

7.    def get_info():
8.        return something_func(ls)
```

нумеровка строк для объяснения.

если я пишу `return ls` между 3 и 4 строкой, я получаю ошибку `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ls' referenced before assignment`(то есть я не могу в любой момент времени получить текущее значение?).

если пишу после 4 - исправно возвращает значение полученное в строке 4.

если `return ls` стоит вместо 4 строки, то возвращается "!", т.е. глобальное значение.

но мне нужно это значение во всех функциях, т.е. в примере я ожидаю что написав `return ls` между 7 и 8 строк я получу значение из 4й строки, однако возвращается "!", то есть в вышестоящих функциях переменная превращается в локальную. как изменять её значение сохранив её глобальность?

Comment: `ls` на 4 строке — не глобальная, а локальная переменная. Чтобы сделать её глобальной, допишите `global ls` после 3 строки

Comment: действительно, спасибо, это решило проблему.
но по поводу `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ls' referenced before assignment` всё равно не понятно, почему если я далее по коду как то изменяю переменную, то я не могу получить её значение до этих изменений?

Comment: оформите коментарий как ответ, я приму его. а по поводу ошибки нашёл ответ в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/358/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-python-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: А что у вас за дичь с `if True:`? :D

Comment: там сложное условие было, чисто для примера поменял, и только потом подумал что его в принципе можно было убрать)