# Как сделать проверку условия при нажатии определенной кнопки?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть три кнопки с названиями животных. Есть поле для ввода пользователем. Нужно привязать к каждой кнопке определенные цвета. 
Не могу понять, что делаю не так. Получаю ошибку KeyError

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Угадай цвет животного")


def output(event):
    guess_matrix = {slon: ['Серый', "Синий"], pchela: ['Желтый', 'Черный'], aist: ['Белый', 'Черный']}
    user_color = entry1.get()
    colors = guess_matrix[user_color]
    if user_color in colors:
        label1['text'] = 'Верно!'
    else:
        label1['text'] = 'Неверно!'


def slon_show(event) :
    label1["text"] = "Введи цвет слона"


def pchela_show(event):
    label1["text"] = "Введи цвет пчелы"


def aist_show(event):
    label1["text"] = "Введи цвет аиста"


label1 = Label(root, width=27, font=15)
label1.grid(row=3, column=0)

slon = Button(root, text="Слон")
slon.grid(row=0, column=0)
slon.bind("<Button-1>", slon_show)

pchela = Button(root,text="Пчела")
pchela.grid(row=0, column=1)
pchela.bind("<Button-1>", pchela_show)

aist = Button(root,text="Аист")
aist.grid(row=0, column=2)
aist.bind("<Button-1>", aist_show)

entry1 = Entry(root, width=10, font=15)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=2)
button4 = Button(root, text="Проверить")
button4.grid(row=2, column=2)
button4.bind("<Button-1>", output)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ключами словаря guess_matrix являются переменные, содержащие объекты кнопок, а не название цвета, которое вы используете в guess_matrix[user_color].
При данной архитектуре кода:

- прописываете для каждой кнопки extra свойство: slon.extra = "slon";
- сохраняете его в глобальную переменную last_button, в каждом из
  *_show обработчиков;
- изменяете ключи словаря на текстовые 'slon', 'pchela' и т.д.;
- получаете доступ к цветам colors = guess_matrix[last_button]

**UPD**:
Глобальные переменные действительно можно завернуть в класс.
По мотивам примера @Twiss с исключением boilerplate кода.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, guess_matrix):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, width=27, font=15)
        self.label.grid(row=3, column=0)

        for idx, animal in enumerate(guess_matrix):
            name, name2, colors = animal
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=name, name=name2)
            btn.grid(row=0, column=idx)
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.animal_show)
            btn.extra = colors

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=10, font=15)
        self.entry1.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Проверить", command=self.output)
        self.button4.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def animal_show(self, event):
        self.animal_colors = event.widget.extra
        self.label["text"] = "Введи цвет {}".format(str(event.widget).split('.')[-1])

    def output(self):
        user_color = self.entry1.get()
        self.label['text'] = 'Верно!' if user_color in self.animal_colors else 'Неверно!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Main((('Слон', 'Слона', ('Серый', 'Синий')),
         ('Пчела', 'Пчелы', ('Желтый', 'Черный')),
         ('Аист', 'Аиста', ('Белый', 'Черный'))
    ))
    root.title("Угадай цвет животного")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Можно сохранять в глобальной переменной свойство кнопок 'text'. Тогда устанавливать extra не понадобится. Но нужно будет соответственно поправить ключи в guess_matrix.

Comment: подскажите , как сделать "сохраняете его в глобальную переменную last_button, в каждом из *_show обработчиков"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/358/306703

Answer (score 1):

Для примера можно реализовать вот так

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, width=27, font=15)
        self.label.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.slon = tk.Button(self, text="Слона", name="slon")
        self.slon.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.slon.bind("<Button-1>", self.animal_show)

        self.pchela = tk.Button(self, text="Пчелы", name="pchela")
        self.pchela.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.pchela.bind("<Button-1>", self.animal_show)

        self.aist = tk.Button(self, text="Аиста", name="aist")
        self.aist.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.aist.bind("<Button-1>", self.animal_show)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=10, font=15)
        self.entry1.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Проверить", command=self.output)
        self.button4.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def animal_show(self, event):
        self.animal = str(event.widget).split('.')[-1]
        self.label["text"] = "Введи цвет {}".format(event.widget["text"])

    def output(self):
        guess_matrix = {"slon": ['Серый', "Синий"], "pchela": ['Желтый', 'Черный'], "aist": ['Белый', 'Черный']}
        user_color = self.entry1.get()
        if user_color in guess_matrix[self.animal]:
            self.label['text'] = 'Верно!'
        else:
            self.label['text'] = 'Неверно!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Main()
    root.title("Угадай цвет животного")
    root.mainloop()
```