# tkinter в разных модулях

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, tkinter, модули

Вопрос версии 2.0

Если с первой частью я разобрался, то тут же возник конфуз.

starter.py

```py
from Packer import resp
from tkinter import *



class Starter:

    win = None
    win = Tk()
    win.title='Press'
    win.geometry("300x300")

    lb = resp().make_label(10,5,win,sider = 'top',bg = 'gold')
    lb0 = resp().make_label(10,5,win,sider = 'bottom', bg = 'blue')

    lb(sider = 'left')
    print(lb0)

    win.mainloop()
```

Packer.py

```py
from tkinter import *


class resp:



    def make_label(self,w,h,frame_name,sider,bg):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.frame_name = frame_name
        self.sider = sider
        self.bg = bg
        lb = Label(frame_name,width = w, height = h, text = 'Это я',bg = bg)
        lb.pack(side=sider)
```

после создания Label'ов в starter.py их объекты превращаются в none и к ним нельзя обратиться. Можно ли, как то поменять значения в Label по ссылкам на них?

Comment: mainloop должно вызываться последним, после инициализации интерфейса (это бесконечный цикл по сути, он крутится пока существует окно, поэтому переход к созданию метки происходит только после того как окно закрыто). Вообще, лучше создание главного окна не прятать поглубже, а делать в основном модуле. А в импортируемых модулях, например, компоновать элементы в фрейм, потом этот фрейм устанавливать в основное окно.

Comment: По текущей версии вопроса вам нужно всего лишь добавить return lb в конце метода make_label

Comment: Вообще, по "архитектуре" приложений советую посмотреть примеры в ответах на эти вопросы: [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/4752653), [Как сделать проверку условия при нажатии определенной кнопки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/873444/1365). По вашему коду - make_label по сути не должно быть внутри класса, а должно быть просто функцией, и нет особого смысла выносить его в отдельный файл.

Comment: а если программа большая и GUI занимает много строк? Мне кажется так удобнее, чтобы основной код GUI был вынесен в отдельный модуль.

Comment: Основной GUI нет смысла целиком выносить в отдельный модуль. Есть смысл разбивать его на части по фреймам, каждый фрейм уже можно выносить. В этом ответе посмотрите второй пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/4752653 Там классы Navbar, Toolbar и т.д. вполне можно вынести. Основной код (MainApplication) остается в основном модуле, но там уже будет не так много кода.