# Как делать проверки с модулем time?

Tags: python

хочу спросить, как приводить различные проверки с модулем time на Python.

**Допустим:  если время на часах будет 12:00, то написать: "тик-так, время уже 12:00"**

И ещё вопрос, время которое считывает модуль, он считывает время с ПК?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запускаете цикл, в нем получаете текущее время на компе и сравниваете. Чтобы не было само-ддоса добавляете задержку (например 300 миллисекунд):

```
import time

while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now.tm_hour == 12 and now.tm_min == 0:
        print("тик-так, время уже 12:00")

    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Аналогичное, но с `datetime`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 12 and now.minute == 0:
        print("тик-так, время уже 12:00")

    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: А при чём здесь модуль `datetime`? Вопрос был про `time`, а Вы на нем только задержку нарисовали.  :)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, спасибо за замечание :) Не знал, что `time` может элементы времени возвращать (часы, минуты, секунды, и т.п.), т.к. использовал его в основном ради `sleep` и получения `time()` (timestamp)

Comment: @gil9red, а localtime, я так понимаю, берёт время с ПК?

Comment: @stepanboi, вместо `while True:` написать `for <элемент> in <коллекция>:`, то, что в треугольных скобках сами подставьте по ситуации. Да, с ПК

Comment: @gil9red, а вот допустим смотри. Я для чего это спрашиваю. Я делаю просто для ВК на LongPoll. И ситуация такая. Я много раз попробовал разные варианты. Но проблема в том, что допустим. Если время 12:00. Он не напишет, пока не напишет любое сообщение, какой-то человек. Только после этого отвечает и всё. Возможно всё таки нужно ставить цикл while?

Comment: Якобы я его заставляю работать. Я хочу так, чтобы он сам написал.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KDFnMtEd. Для понятия, вот код.

Comment: @stepanboi, запускайте тот код с циклом и опросом времени в отдельном потоке. У вас один поток и так занят работой с vk. Пример цикла в потоке: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/rumble%20(vibration)%20a%20xbox%20360%20controller/web/main.py#L225 или вот: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dee38a960d0561ce0d284237647848fc567b6250/multithreading__threading__examples/hello_world__without_daemon.py

Comment: Суть уловил, но не понимаю, как это будет выглядить в моём коде.

Comment: @stepanboi, создайте функцию с тем циклом и проверкой времени, в ней реализуйте отправку сообщения (или что вы там хотели). Проверьте что функция сама по себе при выполнении работает. После создаете объект Thread в него передаете функцию и запускаете его. Этого хватит, чтобы функцию выполнялась в другом потоке

Comment: `def capture_go(chat_id):
    while True:
        now = time.localtime()
        if now.tm_hour == 15 and now.tm_min == 40:
            print("time, to choose")`

Вот функция, как создать объект Thread? Я смотрел, везде по разному.

Comment: @gil9red, я всё сделал. Функция работает, поток выглядит вот так:
`        if __name__ == "__main__":
            thread_= threading.Thread(target=capture_go(chat_id))
            thread_.start()`
Но, он также работает от условия, когда я что-то напишу.

Comment: @stepanboi, разобрались? Молодец :)

Comment: @gil9red, так-то более менее разобрался в модуле, но говорю. Он также работает от условия, когда я что-то напишу. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Не вызывать тот код с time с кодом, обрабатывающим запросы от вк. Или я вас не понимаю. Если не разобрались с этим, создайте отдельный вопрос по этой проблеме

Comment: @gil9red. Смотри. Есть бот. Весь запрос происходит в цикле - for. Всё работает, когда я обращаюсь к какой-то команде. Код, с функцией времени - работает. Но работает, когда я что-то пишу в беседу. Вот видео: https://youtu.be/hha0MEVlYew.

Comment: @stepanboi, а с чего это у вас тот код с capture_go выполняется не глобально, а в контексте какой-то команды? Вы можете в capture_go не передавать чат, а завести глобальный список и в нем хранить chat_id, а в той функции с time при наступлении указанного времени пройтись по списку с char_id и в указанные чаты отправить сообщения

Comment: @gil9red, Как сделать глобальную функцию?

Comment: @stepanboi, создайте ее без отступа, чтобы она не была внутри других блоков (функций, циклов, и т.п.)

Comment: @gil9red, На подобие вот этого? : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/358/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-python-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @stepanboi, да...

Comment: @gil9red, Всё работает. Но, опять же повторюсь, работает оно, от того, когда я что-то напишу. Есть, идея, что если, его завершать, до того момента, когда снова не настанет это время?

Comment: @stepanboi, я щас внимательно посмотрел на ваше видео и понял что у вас поток так и не был создан. Вы в target передали результат выполнения вашей функции, а не саму функцию. Нужно так: ` = Thread(target=<func>, args=(chat_id,))`, тогда у вас будет основной код работать и поток. В следующий раз лучше новый вопрос задавайте и в нем код прикладывайте, это упростит многие моменты, да и вряд ли бы пропустил ту фигню :) Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/66cdbe0a77eb78621700fc97e28c38359b9288af/multithreading__threading__examples/threading_with_webservers__flask.py#L30

Comment: @gil9red, Кажись догоняю. Нужно так? : def run (): def capture_go(chat_Id): (проверка) потом:  for event in longpoll.listen:  captureGo = Thread (target=run, args=(chat_id,)) captureGo.start()

Comment: @stepanboi, похоже на правду :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94884/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red------time).