# Вход на почту через imaplib

Tags: python, tkinter, imap

У меня программа для работы с почтой, у меня есть функции для работы с ней, и мне приходится в каждой функции выходить и заходить на почту по новой, как можно сделать, что бы я один раз зашел и больше не заходил?

```
def login_mail():

 try:

     l = str(login2.get()) # логин для почты 
     p = str(password.get()) # пароль для почты 
     mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com') 
     mail.login(l, p) # заходим на почту 

     date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
     logging.info(date + " Authorization: successfully")
     mb.showinfo("Уведомление", "Вы авторизированы")

 except:

     mb.showinfo("Уведомление", "Ошибка авторизации")
     date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
     logging.error(date + " Authorization: Error")
```

Comment: Не выходите из нее) Без кода трудно что-то сказать.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю часть кода

Comment: это как происходит сам логин на почту, и мне нужно что бы я в каждой функции не делал каждый раз логин, просто дело в том , что если я в этой функции залогинился, то mail не наследуется другими функциями и приходится в каждой функции опять логиниться

Comment: Можно сделать ее глобальной переменной, тогда в принципе будет доступна из других функций.

Comment: А можно пример как это сделать, я с глобальными не работал

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/358/1365

Comment: спасибо за помощь