# telebot: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignmen

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot

x = int(0)

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Мой токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def send(message):
    x += 1
    bot.reply_to(message, "Счетчик: " + str(x))
    
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

писал игрового бота в телеграм и столкнулся с ошибкой UnboundLocalEкror: local variable 'x' referenced before assignmen как я понял он просто не хочет делать вычисления почему?
помогите пожалуйста бот должен при каждой команде старт увеличивать счетчик на единицу

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Глобальные переменные в Python: сохранить локальную переменную от вызова к вызову функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/358/1365)

Answer (score 1):

Так он же пишет в чем ошибка.
Вы пытаетесь обрашаться к переменной, значение которой не было присвоенно.

В данном случае вам надо понимать, что **x** это две разные переменных. Одна глобальная - которую проинициализировали в начале программы. И вторая - это **x** с которой вы работаете внутри функции.

Чтобы работать с глобальной переменной внутри тела функции, то нужно сначала объявить, что она глобальная.

```
def send(message):
    global x
    x += 1
    bot.reply_to(message, "Счетчик: " + str(x))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное